# php within a php statement

Tags: php, wordpress

Using Wordpress, i have a plugin that inserts a playable MP3 on the page.

To call that, along with the track details, this code is inserted;

```
            <?php if (function_exists("insert_audio_player")) {  
              insert_audio_player("[audio:http://thewebsite.com/thetrack.mp3|artists=Artist|titles=Titles]");  
            } ?>
```

I would like to make this editable from the backend easily, by entering some meta-data. So this;

```
<?php meta('track-url'); ?>
```

Along with other various details would replace those that are above.

Unfortunately for me, this;

```
                <?php if (function_exists("insert_audio_player")) {  
              insert_audio_player("[audio:<?php meta('track-url'); ?>|artists=Jack Presto|titles=Track 1]");  
            } ?>
```

obviously does not work! This is down to my lack of understanding if PHP - can anyone help?

Cheers!

Comment: See [PHP: String operators](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php) - you need to glue the parts together using `.`, e.g. `"[audio:".meta("track-url")."|artists...."`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple! Do this:

```
<?php if (function_exists("insert_audio_player")) {
   $trackUrl = meta('track-url');
   insert_audio_player("[audio:$trackUrl|artists=Jack Presto|titles=Track 1]");  
} ?>
```

Comment: Ok, so i went ahead and read the linked part and remembered seeing something similar and kind of combined them all and came out with this;

    <?php $trackartist=get_post_meta($post->ID, 'track-artist', true); ?>
    <?php $trackname=get_post_meta($post->ID, 'track-name', true); ?>
    <?php $trackurl=get_post_meta($post->ID, 'track-url', true); ?>
    <?php if (function_exists("insert_audio_player")) {  
     insert_audio_player("[audio:$trackurl|artists=$trackartist|titles=$trackname]");  
    } ?>

It works, but probably not as clean as it should be?

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

I can't tell if the `meta()` function prints to the screen or returns a string. If it returns a string, do:

```
<?php
if (function_exists("insert_audio_player")) {  
     insert_audio_player('[audio:' . meta('track-url') . '|artists=Jack Presto|titles=Track 1]');  
}
?>
```

If it prints to the screen, it's a bit more complicated. Ideally, you would have a function that DOES return a string, but as a quick hack (if you're only getting paid for a quick fix) you could do something like

```
<?php
if (function_exists("insert_audio_player")) {  
     ob_start();
     meta('track-url');
     $meta = ob_get_contents();
     ob_end_clean();
     insert_audio_player("[audio:$meta|artists=Jack Presto|titles=Track 1]");  
}
?>
```

Comment: It's wordpress, so any function which produces output generally has a `get_whatever()` version to RETURN the output instead.